# How to pass XML input to BIRT 4.9 runtime engine?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, birt, birt-emitter

How to pass XML input to BIRT 4.9 runtime engine? Here is my working around the project (https://github.com/m-thirumal/birt-report), able to generate report output but not with the `XML` data

```
task.getAppContext().put("org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml.inputStream", streamData);
```